# Eloquent not selecting rows

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve some data from my MySQL database, but It's not working using Eloquent (I'm getting 0 rows). I's a very simple query, but is driving me crazy.

**This is the query in PHP:**

```
$slideshowIdList = Media_slideshow::select('idSlideshow')
                                    ->whereIn('idMedia',$idList)
                                    ->groupBy('idSlideshow')
                                    ->get()
                                    ->toArray();
```

**Laravel's query log** shows that the query I wanted to do is okay:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [query] => select `idSlideshow` from `media_slideshow` where `idMedia` in (?) group by `idSlideshow`
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                )

            [time] => 0.49
        )

)
```

And this it the same **query showing the results in Phpmyadmin**:

[image]

The **Media_slideshow model**:

```
class Media_slideshow extends Model
{

    private $idMedia;
    private $idSlideshow;
    protected $table = "media_slideshow";


}
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
Hardcoding the second parameter in `->whereIn()` works. Any clue?

```
->whereIn('idMedia',[11])
```

Comment: Please can you show the code for your `Media_slideshow` model.

Comment: When you `return $slideshowIdList`, there's no data?

Comment: Is $idList an array?

Comment: @Rwd Question edited. I don't think has anything to do!

Comment: @user10971804 the `$slideshowIdList` is empty after doing the query :/

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Yes, and it's required by the `whereIn()` method. You can see that is an array at laravel's log.

Comment: can your try to `echo '<pre>', print_r($slideshowIdList,1); exit();`.. See if it print something.

Comment: @user10971804 It prints an empty array

Comment: print the $idList or just try to replace it with in your case `[11]`.

Comment: @user10971804 The list is already printed in Laravel's query log at the post....

Comment: `whereIn('column', $data)` wants `$data` to be an array not a number or a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$slideshowIdList = Media_slideshow::whereIn('idMedia', $idList)
                                ->groupBy('idSlideshow')
                                ->value('idSlideshow');
$slideshowIdList = $slideshowIdList->toArray();
```

Comment: Put `dd($slideshowIdList);` **before** `$slideshowIdList = $slideshowIdList->toArray();` and please provide the dump here.

Comment: It gives this: `null`

Comment: That's very strange. And doing something like `Media_slideshow::all();` does return results, right?

Comment: Yes, it returns a lot of rows. That's why I'm asking, It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your `$idList` array is wrong. Try to print it as suggested. Refer to my comment above.

Comment: as suggested where